# is Callable interface a thread? i can't run anything while it works

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, callable

i've been working for a while for a simple Maze project, and i got to the point where i need to use the Callable interface as a thread. After implementing and running, i've noticed that while  the callable class runs in the background, i cant seem to work anything else on the background, such as to the an input.

i made a little project the emphasize the problem, see that while the callable class works for 10 seconds, i cant take any input in the meanwhile.
here is the code:

Main class

```
public class Main {

    static ExecutorService service = null;
    static Future<String> task = null;

    public static void main(final String[] argv) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("please enter a command");
        String string = in.readLine();
        while (!string.equals("exit")) {
            if (!string.equals("command")) {
                System.out.println("command not found");
            } else {
                service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
                task = service.submit(new Foo());

                try {
                    final String str;

                    // waits the 10 seconds for the Callable.call to finish.
                    str = task.get(); // this raises ExecutionException if
                                        // thread dies
                    System.out.println(str);
                    service.shutdownNow();
                } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (final ExecutionException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            string = in.readLine();

        }

        //
    }
}
```

the callable class:

```
class Foo implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() {
        try {
            // sleep for 10 seconds
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Callable` is a task

Comment: `// sleep for 10 seconds` `Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);` It's better to write no comment than wrong comments. Luckily this one is pretty obvious.

Comment: `task.get()` _waits_ for the background thread to finish.  (You can infer that from two of the answers below even if they don't come right out and say it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `str = task.get();`.

According to the JavaDoc for Future#get() (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29):

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

If you want the result from your Callable, you have to wait until it's finished.

Comment: alright i think i got it. although it seems pointless to use this interface now, but anyway i understand the problem now. thank you all for helping

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)

> If you would like to immediately block waiting for a task, you can use constructions of the form result = exec.submit(aCallable).get();

That is exactly what you are doing (block the main thread waiting for a task)

Comment: so what is the benefit of using this interface if i can't run simultaneously more threads while this one works?

Comment: You should use the Future object returned by executor.submit(), then you can call isDone() on that element in order to know when the operation is finished. When isDone returns true you can get the result with get() (always called on the Future object)

Answer (score 1):

Callable doesn't do anything in and of itself. It is just a convention interface. To make callable asynchronous, you need to run it in an executor. See https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6 for instance.

Answer (score 1):

> i've noticed that while the callable class runs in the background, i cant seem to work anything else on the background

*...discussion, ... problem explained...*

> it seems pointless to use this interface now.

I don't really know what you were trying to do, but the entire point of `ExecutorService` and `Callable` is to perform tasks in the background.

But what does "in the background" mean?  It means, that while the new thread is off performing some task, the thread that submitted the task can *do something else*.

It looks like this:

```
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);

ReturnType doSomethingInTheBackground() {

    // create the task object
    Callable<ReturnType> task = () -> doSomething();

    // submit the task object
    Future<ReturnType> future = executorService.submit(task);

    doSomethingElse();

    // wait for the result.
    return future.get();
}

private ReturnType doSomething() { ... }

private void doSomethingElse() { ... }
```

The `doSomethingElse()` call is what makes it all worthwhile.  If the calling thread doesn't have anything else to do except wait for the result (i.e., call `future.get()`), then you were right:  There would be no point in using more than one thread.  It would be simpler for the calling thread to just do the task itself.